# Pass big data like images to widget?

Tags: swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

When writing iOS 14 widget, it is easy to pass Strings and other types from app to widgets using @AppStorage:

```
@AppStorage("text", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "…")) var text: String = "Hello World"
```

But how do you pass big data like images to widget? Do you need to use database or shared file storage?

Comment: Thanks! I am reading now.